# Full calendar change date format in week view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar plugin for jQuery in my project. In fullCalendar week view, I can see a row showing the date in following format:-

`Sunday 9/6`, `Monday 9/7`, `Tuesday 9/8` so on...

Actually, I wish to reverse the position of `month/day` to `day/month`.

How shall I initialize the setting? Thanks!

Comment: explode and implode is your friend

Comment: provide some code please

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use the `columnFormat` option to customize this.

```
columnFormat: {
            month: 'ddd',
            week: 'ddd d/M',
            day: 'dddd d/M'
        }
```

Demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/RkWEB/). Let me know if this helps!

Comment: it works!!! and to the person who closed this question: if the question is so "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form", how can ganeshk answered so preciously? Please do not regard something that you do not understand to be meaningless, in this computer world~

Comment: I second that sentiment. I was looking for ways to vote to reopen this question - but couldn't find any.

Comment: n.b - `d` will provide the 0 based ordinal for the day of the week, if you want the day of the month it should be `D`, i.e. `week: `ddd D/M`. Nevertheless, found this very useful.

Comment: I just get OBJECT OBJECT ...
I was looking for this format in week mode "M 16" instead of "Mon 16/4"

Comment: @ganeshk May be it works in full calendar version-3. Could you please suggest how can we set full calendar header dates format to UK date format (day/month/Year) ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `title_format` option in fullcalendar documentation: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/titleFormat/ and set desired format in fullcalendar options.

You can also look [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Option_Hash/) for format options for all calendar views.

Comment: Both links are broken

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using the FullCalendar v3
It seems that the configuration has changed.

You can use the columnHeader Format, Text, or Html properties
As explained in this very nice documentation:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-display

And apply them to different views following this one:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options

Answer (score 1):

You can use any type of date format using `moment`, this is for the fullcalendar `V5 (Version 5)`.
This is the fullcalendar configuration option.

```
dayHeaderFormat: this.dayHeaderFormatUsingMoment,
```

This is the javascript function.

```
dayHeaderFormatUsingMoment(info) {
    return moment(info.date.marker).format("ddd, DD/MM/YYYY"); //output : Tue, 21/07/2020
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
views: {
  week: {
    dayHeaderFormat: {
      // year: 'numeric',
      // month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      weekday: 'short',
    },
  },
},
```

Updated answer: 2023
Output will be: eg: 22 Sun